# Ubuntu 12.04 causing modem to crash

Tags: 12.04, internet, modem, lan

I've noticed that when my Ubuntu PC is running my internet connection drops periodically. The router seems to be ok, but I notice that my modem drops its connection and takes about a minute to reconnect. The connection is pretty good otherwise.

Certain activities seem to reliably cause a crash -if I begin downloading updates via the update manager then I know that within the next few minutes there's a good chance that the connection will crash as I browse the

My Ubuntu HTPC is connected to a router via a wired connection.

Many thanks for your help!!